# Mutt configuration

Tags: linux, mutt

Currently I am using Thunderbird as a mail client, but I am not impressed with that..so planned to switch over mutt client. I have gone through mutt website http://www.mutt.org/doc but unable to figure it out how it will work. So please help me to configure it

Comment: How do you want to configure it?  Typically mutt is used to read mail handled by the system MTA and delivered to your mailbox in your home directory

Comment: What have you tried so far?  How are you accessing your mail? POP3? IMAP? local mbox file or maildir?  What problems are you having?

Answer (score 4):

Configuring Mutt to work with IMAP:

in your .muttrc, the relevant lines are:

```
set folder=imap://dave@apollo
set spoolfile="imap://dave@apollo/INBOX"
```

Perhaps you have been given a username like dave.mackintosh@xdroop.com; your mail server is voyager.xdroop.com; and you are using IMAPS instead of regular IMAP. In this case you need to make your specification as so:

```
set imap_force_ssl=yes
set imap_authenticators="LOGIN"
set imap_keepalive=60
set folder="imap://dave.mackintosh%xdroop.com@voyager.xdroop.com:993"
set imap_user=dave.mackintosh@voyager.xdroop.com
set spoolfile="imap://dave.mackintosh%xdroop.com@voyager.xdroop.com:993/INBOX"
```

Comment: Thank you for this example. I have set as in your example above, my username to handle e-mails via IMAP, i.e.: `username%domain.net@mail.domain.net`. I have also used the complete username (`username@domain.net`) to feed the `imap_user` variable. Still, mutt presets only the `username` part when asking for it, i.e. `Username at mail.domain.net: username`. Why is the `@domain.net` part stripped away?  What do I need to do in order to "fix" this?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have email in your homedir, and you already have a working sendmail, then it should work rather out-of-the-box. What difficulties do you have?

Downloading mail is beyond scope of mutt. If you relay on POP3 or IMAP, use fetchmail to download the mail. Mutt is used to read and compose email, not download.

Configuration is stored in ~/.muttrc

What configuration do you need in the first place?

set spoolfile='~/Maildir'       # where my new mail is located

Possibly something like:

set send_charset="utf8:us-ascii:iso-8859-1:iso-8859-2"

Comment: Mutt can do IMAP.  I know, I read mail with a Mutt configured to use gmail as a mail store.

Comment: @David: oh, that's nice. I didn't know that. I haven't paid attention to mutt for the last 9 years. It simply does its work.